# ERROR 403 in loading resources like CSS and JS in my index.php

Tags: php, css, linux, directory, lampp

I'm in Linux, Elementary OS, and installed lampp in opt.

My CSS and JS won't load. When I inspect my page through browser. The console says
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
I'm really sure that my directories are correct.[image: This is my workspace]

This is the error
[image]

[image]

Comment: My first assumption is permission settings...

Comment: Permission as root? I tried running chromium as root, but no luck.

Comment: Open a terminal, `cd` to the **bootstrap_practice/bootstrap/css** folder, type `ls -la` and add the result to your question so we can see who owns those files. If the localhost web server is Apache but the files are owned by **root**, Apache won't be able to open them.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You need to change permissions on the folder bootstrap/css.
Your super user may be able to access it but it doesn't mean apache or nginx have access to it, that's why you still need to change the permissions.

Tip: I usually make the apache/nginx's user group owner of that kind of folders and give 775 permission to it.

Comment: It should work if you do "sudo chmod 0777" inside that directory.

Comment: For directories: chmod 755 and for files chmod 644. Run these two at the root of your site: `find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;` `find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;`

Comment: i have solved it by adding permission the folder - some time adding permission  to individual file is not enough

Comment: @danielad that's right, the folder needs execute permission to be accessible

Answer (score 17):

Find out the web server user

open up terminal and type
`lsof -i tcp:80`

This will show you the user of the web server process
Here is an example from a raspberry pi running debian:

```
COMMAND   PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
apache2  7478 www-data    3u  IPv4 450666      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2  7664 www-data    3u  IPv4 450666      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2  7794 www-data    3u  IPv4 450666      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

The user is `www-data`

If you give ownership of the web files to the web server:

```
chown www-data:www-data -R /opt/lamp/htdocs
```

And chmod 755 for good measure:

```
chmod 755 -R /opt/lamp/htdocs
```

Let me know how you go, maybe you need to use 'sudo' before the command, i.e.
`sudo chown www-data:www-data -R /opt/lamp/htdocs`

if it doesn't work, please give us the output of:
`ls -al /opt/lamp/htdocs`

Answer (score 1):

A fast solution can be change permissions with:

```
sudo chmod -R 755
```

If you are managing a production server be careful and dont add a permission that you dont need.