# Magento (403 error for Css and Js and images)

Tags: magento

I have created a new Package for Magento. Every thing is fine on the local host css, js and images are working.

While today for practice i make a new store online. But the css, js and images are not working. There is the 403 error when i am viewing it in the browser (console).

Comment: Url of the store is http://nordiff.biz/nor/

Comment: The files aren't there.  The stylesheet it's trying to load is `http://nordiff.biz/nor/skin/frontend/base/default/css/styles.css` but if you navigate to that directory (which you shouldn't be able to do, you need to fix your permissions), you'll see that in `http://nordiff.biz/nor/skin/frontend/base/default/css/` there's only a file called widgets.css

Comment: It should be a permission issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18724842/2568469

Comment: Have you specified the package in the backend?  Magento will look in base as its at the end of the fallback hierarchy when it can't find the files in the path specified in the backend (or can't load them due to permissions as Hatef points out).

Comment: Thanks, McNab But still i have some confusions regarding it. I made a new Package and activate it in the backend every thing is going correct but my css and js is not uploading at run time. I aslo specified in the backend. While i am using the theme under the default folder. I hard to find out the solution but nothing.

Comment: 1 minute i made a new package from scratch now you are saying that it will load the css and js from base theme. Why ? I want to run it from my custom package.