# Error 403 loading css and jquery file on mac os x using xampp

Tags: css, macos, apache, xampp

Error 403 loading css and jquery file on mac os x using xampp.

I have already tried [ERROR 403 in loading resources like CSS and JS in my index.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724718/error-403-in-loading-resources-like-css-and-js-in-my-index-php)

but it doesnt work . Any other solution?

I Might be changing the wrong permision file name. anyone knows the right command line. (Command line newbie here)

Files works previously on my previous MAc os x installation .

Files are already in htdocs folder htdocs/webpage_test/css

Comment: Using latest version of xampp

Comment: what is the location of the css-file?

Comment: @W.Q. nested inside htdocs directory

Comment: @W.Q. Files works previously on my previous installation (i just can't remember how i fix it last time) (As i have reformated my mac)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your premissions are not correct configured.

Try this:

1. Open   “xamppapacheconfextrahttpd-xampp.conf” (in notepad ++ for
   example)
2. Replace the line “Allow from localhost” with “Allow from
   127.0.0.1″ (be careful you will have to do this for the 2 lines!)
3. Save file
4. Restart apache, you’re done!

([Source](http://www.inpixelitrust.fr/blog/en/xampp-security-access-forbiden-and-403-error/))

Comment: i am on mac os x that file only exist in windows?