# ERROR 403 in loading resources like CSS in my index.php

Tags: php, css, apache

I got the problem when loading css file in my index.php.
I already follow the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724718/error-403-in-loading-resources-like-css-and-js-in-my-index-php) but it is not successful.

In index.php, I used this code:

```
 <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

When I check the `lsof -i tcp:80`, the result is

> httpd   4896       root    4u  IPv6 324899      0t0  TCP *:http
>   (LISTEN)

And I change the owner and permission of css folder as the answer

```
 drwxr-xr-x. 15 apache     apache      4096 Dec 23 00:40 css
```

EDIT: the permission of css file

```
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 apache apache  99548 Apr  5  2014 bootstrap.min.css
```

But it still get this

> You don't have permission to access /css/bootstrap.min.css on this
>   server.

Comment: What are the file's permissions? Can you post your apache config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from SELinux

```
SELinux is preventing httpd from read access on the file
```

So, my solution: running command

setsebool -P httpd_read_user_content 1

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions of that folder and those files in the server, and whether you can access them with your current permissions.

If not give them the 775 permission.

Answer (score 0):

What about the files permission? They are owned by apache as well?
The best way to enforce the right permissions is to make apache the owner of the files as well.

Maybe doing a recursive chown can solve it.

```
chown -R apache:apache css
```

Another possible issue is the fact that your assets are relative the file where they are being included from.
If your index is on `foo/index.php` and you asset is on `foo/asset/css` or `bar/css` they will not be found since you are using the relative notation:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

If your index and css folder are on the same level you might use:

```
<link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: I already run command `chown` as your answer. It change owner from my acc to apache as you see in my question, but it is still not working. The link is correct, I don't need change anything.