# Drupal site not accessing CSS and JS files

Tags: javascript, css, drupal, permissions

I have a web application running on Drupal. the site is not loading properly, for some reason its not getting access to the css and js files.Here is the error I am getting on the browser console.

The SSL certificate used to load resources from https://sitename.com will be distrusted in M70. Once distrusted, users will be prevented from loading these resources. See https://g.co/chrome/symantecpkicerts for more information.

date.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

views.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

datepicker.1.7.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

pls how can i reolve this.

Comment: 403 usually means the server process doesn't have read permissions on the file / folder - if the resource is on your site.  If not do you need some sort of api / security key to be allowed to use them

Comment: Have a look at this - may be connected as I think Drupal is php - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724718/error-403-in-loading-resources-like-css-and-js-in-my-index-php