# Stylesheet, Image not loading while it was linked to the index.php file from the header

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, stylesheet

For some reason I can't link my files and external stylesheet, external JS files to my index.php file.

I have linked index.php to style.css from the directory akobuy > styles folder:

[image]

I tried several options but it doesn't seem to load the stylesheet:

```
 1. <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css">
 2. <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/style.css">
 3. <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles/style.css">
 4. <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Akobuy/styles/style.css">
```

Same is happening with JS and images:

[image]

I tried several other editors same issues.

Comment: Can you display the result also

Comment: try refreshing the page by using ctrl+f5

Comment: like @ZeeshanAhmadKhalil say, try hard refresh using ctrl + f5 and open `inspect element` and check `network` tab, are you see your `css` and `js` in there?

Comment: Permissions maybe? Are those files readable?

Comment: Can you read/open `http://whateveryourdomain.is/styles/style.css`?

Comment: I tried hard refresh but it didn't work as well - I will inspect element and let you know if this is actually working.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles/style.css">
```

Related with your images. `../` mean back to parent.

Comment: Hello Everyone, I tried <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles/style.css"> but the result seems to be the same. it does link to the CSS stylesheet

Comment: I inspected the page and it seems that all of links or JS script are not linked for some reason: GET http://localhost/akobuy/styles/bootstrap-337.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)
index.php:13 GET http://localhost/akobuy/font-awsome/css/font-awesome.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)
index.php:14 GET http://localhost/akobuy/styles/style.css net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)

Comment: I think project php run on a server, so how about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724718/error-403-in-loading-resources-like-css-and-js-in-my-index-php

Comment: Thanks @thucnguyen !