# Urls in css is not working after upload static files to aws s3 bucket

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I making a blog posting web site and also check different cors
configurations for aws but any of this can solve this issue.Issue is
urls in css files like

```
   @import url(fonts.css); background-image:
url("paper.gif");
```

and like these things is not working.And also in
console I got a error like this

```
net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)
```

so any
of font awesome icons are also not working.Do you have any suggestion
let me know.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724718/error-403-in-loading-resources-like-css-and-js-in-my-index-php

Comment: Are these web assets served from S3 or from your web server? If served from S3, are they public?

Comment: @jarmod yeah they are public

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you in bucket policy is blocked the other urls. therefore they don't allow to any other url to interfere your bucket objects.And the solution for this question is first you have to do is disable block all public acces in permission [image: picture of after block all public access].After that add this to bucket policy

```
    {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::dtblog/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then you good to go.